# Centre vertically the title of the bar button iOS7

Tags: ios, ios6, ios7

I need to centre vertically the title of the bar button and the button itself, as you can see from the code below, I tried to use `setTitlePositionAdjustment` and `setBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment`.

I expected:

- `setTitlePositionAdjustment` to change the title position, however it
  changed the position of my background image.
- `setBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment` to change background image
  position, however it didnt make any difference

I am a bit confused of this behaviour as the same code worked fine for iOS6. And I am looking for any solution to centre `UIButtonItem` title vertically. Thank you for your time and help in advance.

```
 +(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItemWithTitle:(NSString *)title Color:(UIColor *)color    Target:(id)target Action:(SEL)action{

  UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:title style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:target action:action];
  [barButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"standardButtonBackgroundHighlight"]];
  [barButton setBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment:-2.0 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
  [barButton setTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(1, 2) forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

   NSShadow *shadow = [[NSShadow alloc ]init];
   shadow.shadowColor = [UIColor clearColor];
   NSDictionary *attributes = @{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor redColor],
                                 NSShadowAttributeName: shadow,
                                 NSFontAttributeName : /*pass the font*/ };
   [barButton setTitleTextAttributes:attributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];


return barButton;
}
```

Not using storyboard or nibs.

Answer (score 0):

Try to play with the frame of UIButton as custom view for UIBarButtonItem.

```
    *infoBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [infoBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(infoClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [infoBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [infoBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn-selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [infoBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, 60.f, 20.f)];
    UIBarButtonItem *barBtnItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:barBtn];
```

Comment: hello, thank you for your answer. However, my code is doing the same thing, the only difference is that I am using background image and setting the width of the button based on the button title length. The problem is that I cant move the title inside the button.